# What Dimensionality Reduction method I can follow on a dataset that has Physics Parameter?

Tags: dimensional-analysis, data-analysis, data, dimensional-regularization

I am trying to model data related to **Locomotive Train**. We have a various set of parameters and we have the possibility to generate a few more parameters from this. Our model is currently using a lot of parameters due to which it takes more time during computation. Since we have a lot of feature parameters and there is a good level of importance each parameter carries on the final parameter, I would like to know the best dimensionality reduction methods that are suitable for this kind of *data which has physics parameters*.

Comment: Could you list the variables you already have? Do you know which products of powers of the variables are dimensionless?

Comment: I have variables like acceleration, horsepower, weight, number of the CAR, the weight of each car and so on.

Comment: Your variables (and their dimensions) include acceleration ($LT^{-2}$), power ($L^2MT^{-3}$), and the total mass ($M$). We can multiply the latter by some multiple of gravity, another acceleration, to get the frictional force the engine's power must cancel out, viz. $P_\text{friction-canceller}=F_\text{friction}v$ for $v$ the train's speed. What do you want to estimate with dimensional analysis?